# Populate Dropdown based on another Dropdown Using Ajax, jQuery and Codeigniter on Update

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, codeigniter

I have created a dropdown that populates another dropdown.

I have created a modal for update in my application and I want the selected value of the dropdown to be the name taken from the database. It shows the name, but the problem is it doesnt show the other names which should be included.

(Note that the names show up depending on the first dropdown)

Here is my Model

```
function get_agents($campaign_id)
{
    $campaign_id1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($this->db->conn_id,trim($campaign_id));
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT tbl_employee.emp_id, CONCAT(tbl_applicant.fname, ' ', tbl_applicant.lname) AS fullname FROM tbl_applicant INNER JOIN tbl_employee ON tbl_employee.apid=tbl_applicant.apid INNER JOIN tbl_account ON tbl_employee.acc_id=tbl_account.acc_id WHERE tbl_account.acc_id='".$campaign_id1."' ORDER BY tbl_applicant.fname ASC");
    return $query->result();
}
```

Here is my Controller

```
public function getAgents()
{
   $campaign_id = $this->input->post('campaign_id');
   $data = $this->KudosModel->get_agents($campaign_id);
   echo "<option value=''>-- Select Ambassador Name --</option>";
   foreach($data as $a)
   {
       echo "<option value='".$a->emp_id."'>".$a->fullname."</option>";
   }
}
```

Here is my View

```
<div class="form-group" style="height: auto; overflow: auto;">
<label class="col-sm-3 control-label float-left">Ambassador Name</label>
<div class="col-sm-9">
    <select class="form-control" id="agentNames<?php echo $val->kudos_id; ?>" required="true" data-trigger="change" value="<?php echo $val->ambassador; ?>">
        <option selected="" value="">-- Select Ambassador Name --</option>
        <option selected="selected" value=""><?php echo $val->ambassador;?></option>
        <?php 
        foreach($name2 as $row)
        {
            if($val->campaign==$row->acc_name)
                echo '<'; if($val->ambassador==$row->fullname){
                    echo 'selected=selected';
                }echo'option value="'.$row->emp_id.'">'.$row->fullname.'</option>';
            }
        ?>
    </select>
</div>
```

Here is my JQuery

```
$('#addCampaign<?php echo $val->kudos_id; ?>').on('change', function(){
        $.ajax({
            type : 'POST',
            data : 'campaign_id='+ $('#addCampaign<?php echo $val->kudos_id; ?>').val(),
            url : "<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/Kudos/getAgents/",
            success : function(data){
                //data returns your name, iterate through it and add the name to another select
                $('#agentNames<?php echo $val->kudos_id; ?>').html(data);
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: As you were told in your last question, this is a bad approach. A much better way is to return JSON from the server and build the HTML in your success function. Anyway, in your view it looks like you're going to end up with `<selected=selectedoption value="...` for one of the options; that's precisely the kind of mistake that is prevented by separating data and presentation.

Comment: How should I do it?

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't a free programming school; start with php's `json_encode` and learn about constructing DOM elements with JS.